# SQL Server real/float precision changing during SSIS import to MS-Access database

Tags: database, ms-access, ssis, types, precision

I am using SSIS to grab the results from 2 Views in a SQL Server database, union them (with appropriate mapping), filter them and place them into an Access database.

This process is working, but the precisions of certain data are changing.

I was already aware of the normal float/real problem of storing approximate values (e.g. [SQL Server makes up extra precision for floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203069/sql-server-makes-up-extra-precision-for-floats)), however the views being referenced by SSIS ("data transfer views") are selecting from other views ("part level views", which convert from nvarchars to real/float) which explicitly convert in the following way:

```
,CONVERT(real,ISNULL(FieldName, 0)) AS Alias
```

and appear in the data transfer view results to 2 d.p.
The Access column is defined as a Number with Field size=Double, Decimal places=2).

Yet, the float/real *approximated* value is being displayed in access, rather than the figure to 2 d.p.

The access fields must be Number and not Text, so I can't recast to nvarchar.

Is there a simple solution to this?

**Update:** Changing the field size from Double to Single fixes this issue.
Why does the Field size of Double change the precision of the number and why does it not display it according to the specified number of decimal places for a Double?

Comment: As @HansUp has explained, the decimal places property of a Jet/ACE field has no effect on precision of storage, only on default display format. If you need to control precision of the decimals, you have to use a Decimal field, but that is very poorly supported in Jet/ACE (not at all in the UI, in fact). Currency fields store decimals to 4 places, so that's one alternative that many people use when they don't need greater precision.

Comment: Last of all, if you cast your source data to use a fixed number of decimal places, it would be stored with the exact decimal values you append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Access Help topic for DecimalPlaces Property:

"Note  The DecimalPlaces property setting has no effect if the Format property is blank or is set to General Number."

So try modifying the field's Format property, to see if you can get what you want displayed.

Comment: In general, when one has a question about the differences between two Access/Jet/ACE data types, the Help file is the obvious place to start.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks guys. This is my first use of SSIS and use of Access as a data destination, so finding out which application's help to look at or which part of the process wasn't working as I expected was tricky. Thanks.